# Json, Jackson and serialization

Tags: java, json

I've started to using Json with Jackson library and i found little problem.

I'm creating Json object:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, Object> userInMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

then i'm adding fields:

```
userInMap.put("user", "active");
userInMap.put("uuid", uuid);
```

And after all when im trying to output this object i have Json object but without `"`, i mean i supposed to have:

```
{"user":"active", "uuid":"lasdnfa"}
```

but i have:

```
{user:active, uuid:lasdnfa}
```

and another thing - i want to add this object to memcache, but before i do this, i have to serialize this object. How i can serialize Json object?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by serializing Json object? Objects are serialized to Json string...

Comment: I assume you did a `System.out.println(userInMap);`. That calls the toString() method of an object to get a string representation of it. It has nothing to do with JSON. You have to use a JSON library.

Comment: I mean, the object will be written as String - i can do .toString , but i'm not sure if it's the best way...

Comment: @devconsole - ok, so how i can write in console Json object, not using System.out.println? i should serialize it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `toString()` on your object, you might need your mapper to output the value this way :

`System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(userInMap)));`